# Action filter - dependency injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, action-filter

I using:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
```

When I try to create new ActionFilter i need have access to other services so I try write standard constructor inject but when my costructor have parameters I have to write something like that:

```cs
[OAuthFilter(serviceToInject)]
```

I cant to that becouse action filters can't have this kind of parameters.

What I should do? Action filters can't have a inject constructors?

Comment: @Steven that is for ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET 4, this is ASP.NET Core

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: The answer is still the same: Make your attributes either [passive](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/) or [Humble objects](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TypeFilterAttribute`:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(OAuthFilter))]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

This will instantiate your filter and get any needed components through dependency injection. Another alternative is the `ServiceFilterAttribute`:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(OAuthFilter))]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
}
```

But this requires that you add your filter to the service collection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<OAuthFilter>();
}
```